# nth root kerning problem with unicode-math font override

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math, kerning

I am using both `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` to different meanings and expecting different characters to appear.

I recently switched to XeTeX and started using new fonts (*TeX Gyre Pagella* in this example) with the packages `fontspec` and `unicode-math`. As suggested by [the answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120065/xetex-what-happened-to-mathcal-and-mathscr#120070), I override `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` with characters coming from a different font (XITS-math).

Unfortunately this has the effect of mangling the setting of a (seemingly) unrelated math symbol : the nth root.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% Math font overrides ----
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},
             StylisticSet=1,Extension=.otf,BoldFont=*bold]{xits-math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Extension=.otf,BoldFont=*bold]{xits-math}

\begin{document}
Some math letters:
\[ \mathbb{C} \mathcal{C} \mathscr{C} \mathfrak{C} \]

Here's a big $n$-th root:
\[ F_k(x,y,z)  = \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^{k} f_i^n} \,. \]
\end{document}
```

This code produces the following result:
[image: Mangled nth root]
All *C*s are different, but the *n* is too close from the radical symbol (√).

Commenting out the math font overrides yield the correct result for the nth root (but `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`  now produce identical characters):
[image: correct nth root]

My questions are then

- Why does overriding `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` affects the setting of the nth root ?
- How can I avoid this problem ? (or do I have to change fonts ?)

Comment: while waiting for experts you can use `\sqrt[n\;]` to improve the looks...

Comment: `\setmathfont` overwrites the math fontdimens, and the one from xits are not suitable for pagella. There is no good solution for this problem, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375243/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is it theoretically envisionable that `unicode-math` avoids overriding math fontdimens not relevant for `\mathcal`, `\mathscr` range?

Comment: This particular situation will be fixed in the next version of unicode-math. (Assuming that the first maths font loaded is the one that drives the majority of the formatting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

Imho with a current unicode-math (2/2018) this is no longer needed.

=====

It looks as if it could work if you reset the fontdimens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\ExplSyntaxOn 
 %store the values
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{65}{\tl_set:cx{l_tmp_fontdimen_#1_tl}{\the\fontdimen #1  \l__um_font }}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Math font overrides ----
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},
             StylisticSet=1,Extension=.otf,BoldFont=*bold]{xits-math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Extension=.otf,BoldFont=*bold]{xits-math}


\ExplSyntaxOn
%restore the values
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{65}{\fontdimen #1  \l__um_font =\tl_use:c{ l_tmp_fontdimen_#1_tl}}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}
Some math letters:
\[ \mathbb{C} \mathcal{C} \mathscr{C} \mathfrak{C} \]

Here's a big $n$-th root:
\[ F_k(x,y,z)  = \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^{k} f_i^n} \,. \]
\end{document}
```

But this is quite experimental ... and only tested with xelatex. (And probably they are still wrong for the other math styles).

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, thanks !
Additionally LuaLaTeX did not have this problem, so another solution  could be using LuaLaTeX instead of XeTeX

Comment: The root is defined differently in both engines  but with lualatex you can get similar problems. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364328/2388.