In TeX Live 2024, why does \substack insert a vertical gap between the lines when STIXMath-Regular is loaded?
Feeding
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}% “TeX Gyre Termes Math” instead of “Latin Modern Math” would do as well.
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf,range={}]{STIXMath-Regular}%%% leave the range empty or insert some unrelated Unicode codes there.
\begin{document}
\[\substack{1\\2}\]
\end{document}

to lualatexs from TeX Live 2023 and TeX Live 2024 yields the following outputs, compared with diffpdf (left=2023, right=2024):

For no good reason, a vertical gap between the lines has appeared. The same problem shows up when using inline math \(…\) instead of block math \[…\]. Is the appearance of the gap a bug or an official change of the user interface? In the former case, any fix? In the latter case, how to remove the gap?
Crosspost: http://github.com/latex3/unicode-math/issues/636 .

You do get warnings in 2023 that stixmath isn't a math font that font issue was fixed in STIX Two and if you use \setmathfont[range={}]{STIX Two Math} you get the close space in both cases. There were some changes in the handling of such fonts but I'm not sure if this is expected you could raise an issue at the fontspec github oh I see you did.

reset the math values after the call to stix with \setmathfont[range={\int}]{Latin Modern Math}

see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364319/2388

@UlrikeFischer Thx! Works like a charm at least on this example. Even \setmathfont[range={}]{Latin Modern Math} does the job.

@DavidCarlisle Thx! I've got so many warnings in my non-minimal book that I've been ignoring them for years. Anyhow, “stixmath isn't a math font” sounds like a bug. Are the symbols from STIX Two Math at least somewhat similar to those from  STIXMath-Regular so that I can attempt to switch to STIX Two Math also for a large document? STIX Two Math for the minimal example here works like a charm.

stix v1 didn't properly declare itself as a math font in the internal opentype tables (which is one reason why Khaled forked it to make xits and in the end it was replaced by stix 2)

Good question! But voting to close, as it was answered in the comments.

@Davislor These are different questions. Even if they have similar solutions (and even if the cause of the issues is the same or similar).

I agree with the OP that it is not a duplicate, voting to leave open.

Based on David's and Ulrike's comments,
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
%%% Use STIX or STIX Two for some symbols; put them into range{…}:
%\setmathfont[Extension=.otf,range={"2040}]{STIXMath-Regular}%%% This line causes a warning in the log (“Script 'Math' not explicitly supported within font 'STIXMath-Regular'”) and a big superfluous vertical gap in \substack{…\\…}; cf. http://github.com/latex3/unicode-math/issues/636 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/721050 .  Therefore, we use:
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf,range={"2040}]{STIXTwoMath-Regular}%%% with this line, \substack{…\\…} leaves only a small vertical gap with STIX Two Math.
%%% Now you need the next line to avoid superfluous superfluous vertical gap in \stackrel{…}{…}, \frac{…}{…}, and underbrace{…}_{…}:
\setmathfont[range={}]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}% leave the value of the range parameter empty or put \int there.
\begin{document}%
\(\stackrel{\text{def}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \frac{m}{n}\ \substack{1\\2} \underbrace{\langle\rangle\dotsm \langle\rangle}_{k\ \text{terms}}\)
\end{document}


Ideally, we'd like to have an easier, conceptually simpler way of getting new chars from STIX Two Math without causing extra issues (and I don't know any such way); cf. http://github.com/latex3/unicode-math/issues/637 .
